# Unable to calculate scores for PCA manually that match what princomp is producing

Tags: r, pca

Using this script:

```
d <- iris[1:4]
pca = princomp(d, cor=TRUE)

d2 <- scale(d, scale = FALSE)

m1 <- matrix(as.numeric(d[1,1:4]),1,4)
m2 <- matrix(pca$loadings,4,4)

mf1 <- m1 %*% m2
mf2 <- m2 %*% t(m1)
```

I can't get the matrix multiplcation results (either mf1, or mf2) to match the results of running `pca$scores`. My understanding is that the values times the loadings returns the score, but I'm missing something (presumably simple).

Is there a default standardization that princomp applies?

Comment: It's hard to believe you could not have found the answer with the obvious search: `[r] princomp pca`

Comment: If you're able to find an answer with that search, please if you could share the exact link. I've tried several different searches, including that one that you recommended. I wasn't able to find an answer.

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood your question. Looking at the code it becomes apparent that `princomp` scales the results when delivering the scores. I don't see any scaling in your effort. (There is an answered question that asked how to find the code for princomp.)

Comment: Take a look at what `princomp()` does: `stats:::princomp.default`.

Comment: What is that scaling though? I tried `scale(d, scale = apply(d, 2, sd, na.rm=TRUE), center = FALSE)` and didn't get the results either.